# Showing only 1 toastr

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We're using angular-toastr.js in our application. We have the following directive used in all our edit forms:

```js
 app.directive('serverError', ['resourceFactory','spinnerService', 'toastr', function (resourceFactory,spinnerService,toastr) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {

                var errorToastConfig = {closeButton:true,timeOut:0,tapToDismiss:true};

                $scope.$on('sm:badRequest', function (event, data) {

                    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                        if (value.message == '') value.message = 'The ' + value.property + ' value is invalid.'
                    });

                    $scope.errors = data;
                    //$scope.alertMessage = resourceFactory.getResource('Messages', 'errorOnForm');
                    //$scope.alertType = 'error';
                    $timeout(function () {
                        spinnerService.stopSpinner();
                    }, 0);
                    toastr.clear();
                    var errorMsg = ($scope.errors[0] && $scope.errors[0].message?$scope.errors[0].message:resourceFactory.getResource('Messages', 'errorOnForm'));

                    toastr.error(errorMsg, errorToastConfig);
                    $scope.disableAction = false;
                });
```

The problem is that when the page encounters a bad request I see 3 toastr messages on the screen instead of just 1. One is coming from my controller's code and 2 from this directive as this code is executed twice by angular. Adding toastr.clear() doesn't resolve the issue. Ideally, I don't want to run the code at all if the error is handled by the controller's code already. Otherwise I want to make sure I only display one toastr with the error information. Do you see what needs to be changed in the above?

UPDATE. I can also show our main app.js code to handle bad requests. When I am debugging the code I can see that the directive code fires twice and the toastrs array is empty when the call is executed.

This is app's code:

```js
app.factory('badRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 400) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("sm:badRequest", rejection.data);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);

    app.factory('noConnectionInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', function ($rootScope, $q) {
        return {
            
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                console.dir(rejection);
                if (rejection.status === -1) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("sm:noConnection");
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent having identical toasts stack by setting the `preventDuplicates` property to `true`.

> From docs: Duplicates are matched to the previous toast based on their message
>   content.

Just add the property to your `errorToastConfig`:

```
var errorToastConfig = {closeButton:true,timeOut:0,tapToDismiss:true, preventDuplicates:true};
```

See [docs](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr#prevent-duplicates) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work although it looks like a very helpful property. I'm thinking the reason is that the toasters are created in different scopes and that's why toastr.clear() or that extra property has no effect. The app.js has interceptors of the bad request, like I just added to my original message. When I debug, I can see that the code in the directive fires twice and the toasters array is empty.

Comment: I don't know if this may help but have you tried these other properties `preventOpenDuplicates` or `maxOpened`?

Comment: I'll try, but I think I need to figure out why the directive code fires twice - that's the main concern. May be I have this directive in several forms - need to find out.

Comment: Ok, I found that our _Layout.cshtml form has the following in the middle of the page  <section id="loginForm">
                        <form name="changePasswordForm" novalidate role="form" data-server:error class="ng-cloak">. So, it looks like this one is hit first, then the actual form that produced bad request. The question is what do I need to do now. Can I remove that from our main layout or would I have to remove server-error from all our edit forms?

Comment: Turned out I can not just remove it from the forms as it was resetting some important properties such as DisableAction. But I'm working on a slightly different solution now - testing it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to be of some help.:)